# NSWorkspace.shared.open(_:) not working as expected

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

Previously, I used [`NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1525235-openfile) to open a file (in this case a PDF) in the default application for the file.

```
import SwiftUI

Button {
    NSWorkspace.shared.openFile("/path/to/file.pdf")
} label: {
    Text("Open PDF in Preview")
}
```

Because deprecated, I tried to use [`NSWorkspace.shared.open(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1533463-open):

```
import SwiftUI

Button {
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "/path/to/file.pdf")!)
} label: {
    Text("Open PDF in Preview")
}
```

However, this results in a “The application can’t be opened.” error with code -50 when clicking the button. Any workaround?

Comment: What you have in the second example isn't a valid URL